# ansible - define hosts/tag from dynamic inventory in the host file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using `ec2.py` and specific tag on ec2 instances to get my hosts, the results are shown as list of IP addresses, for example:

The results from ec2.py:

```
 "tag_test_staging": [
    "10_80_20_47"
  ],
```

I define the tag in my playbook `- hosts: tag_Name_test` and it is run on all the instances with `tag_Name_test`.

Is there a way to define the hosts/tag in the `hosts` file under the `inventory/` folder and the playbook will take the hosts from there instead of specify the ec2 tag directly on the playbook like now ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already go to the right direction.

Suppose you got dynamic inventory by `ec2.py` and it is `tag_test_staging`.  So you can build inventory folder and files as below

```
inventory 
  staging
    hosts
    group_vars
      all.yml
      tag_test_staging.yml
      tag_Name_test.yml
```

You add the variable define in each YAML file. the variable in `tag_test_staging.yml` will be only applied to the instance with that tag.

So now you can apply your playbook as:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/staging your_playbook.yml
```

There is a best practices document on how to [use dynamic inventory with clouds](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#use-dynamic-inventory-with-clouds), please take a look as well.

Comment: thank you, I am new to ansible, so how I can define it as variable in the YAML file ?

Comment: It's actually my question - how I can define the variable on the inventory file instead of `- hosts: tag_Name_test` on the playbook