# directory structure for more complex server scopes

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I just read some Ansible best practises but all of them just worked with dev, test and prod stages. For me, it's a bit more complex. I have servers like this:

- application dev server
- application test server
- application prod server
- jira test server
- jira prod server
- solr prod server
- jenkins build slave

And I'm struggeling when I try to define my inventories. Because there are multiple scenarios which can happen:

- execute a playbook on all *app server* (dev + test + prod)
- execute a playbook on all *app prod server*
- execute a playbook on all *prod server* (apps + jira + solr)

So how would a directory layout look like for this case? And where to define host- and environment-specific variables? And how would I execute my playbooks (w/ or w/o `--limit`?)

Answer (score 1):

Best practice practice is always not the best for every use case. For your particular use it should be as described given below:

Create multiple inventories in a flat way and classify in terms of servers based functionality. For instance, have separate inventories for each environment:

```
application dev server inventory
application test server inventory
application prod server inventory
jira test server inventory
jira prod server inventory
solr prod server inventory
jenkins build slave inventory
```

while each inventory will have a classical structure like:

[image]

Once you have all these inventories, you can have collection of simple shell scripts that can compose multiple playbooks, for instance shell script for app servers would be:

```
echo "***********************************"
echo "****INFO:- Performing deployment: on app servers"
echo "***********************************"
ansible-playbook $deploy_component_playbook1 -i $INVENTORY_PATH/application-dev-server/hosts --extra-vars " " # define env varaibles inside " "
ansible-playbook $deploy_component_playbook2 -i $INVENTORY_PATH/application-test-server/hosts --extra-vars " "  # define env varaibles inside " "
ansible-playbook $deploy_component_playbook3 -i $INVENTORY_PATH/application-prod-server/hosts --extra-vars " " # define env varaibles inside " "
```

Define these variables `deploy_component_playbook1, deploy_component_playbook2, deploy_component_playbook3` with your respective playbook names with absolute/relative path.

A variable `INVENTORY_PATH` should be the absolute path of you inventory director, where all different inventories are placed.

Environment variables can be defined as i mentioned after `--extra-vars` inside " ".

Similarly you can have a shell script for your other combination of playbooks. At the end all you need is to launch the desired shell script.

Comment: `you can have collection of simple shell scripts that can compose multiple playbooks` - hm, so there is no "ansible built-in" solution for my usecase? E.g. something like tagging hosts and execute on all hosts with certain tags?

Comment: As far as i know, you can use tags when you have a long playbook with a number of different tasks, then you can use tags to execute only particular task from a playbook. However, regarding tagging the hosts, i never tried and also it depends how you have your inventories arranged. With the approach i defined above it seems difficult to have tagging because a playbook needs inventory right at the time of execution.

You can also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643684/ansible-define-hosts-tag-from-dynamic-inventory-in-the-host-file, may be useful regarding tagging hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Our inventory is not much complicated so we could manage with groups and subgroups as below.

```
[app_prod]
appserverslist.xyz.com
[jira_prod]
jiraserverslist.xyz.com
[application:children]
app_prod
app_stage
app_test
[jira:children]
jira_prod
jira_test
jira_stage
[application:vars]     # variables to all groups
xyz=10
[app_prod:vars]        # variables to individual group
http_port=88
[all:vars]             # variables to all hosts
ansible_ssh_user=xyz
```

However we use dynamic inventory files extensively (query a database and get the lists of hosts).